# SELECT the same column with different AS

Tags: mysql

I've been searching for this for a couple of hours; not sure if I'm missing a keyword or if this is just an uncommon expectation, but here's the situation:

I'd like to select the same column from the same table multiple times in a single query. I want the end result to have exactly ONE row.

A basic example would be:

> SELECT `last` AS `firstLast`, `last` AS `secondLast` FROM
>   `table` WHERE `last` = 'name' OR `last` = 'other' LIMIT 1

The idea being: firstLast should contain the result when last is equal to name, secondLast should contain the result when last is equal to other.

The end result should look like this:

- name other

The current result I'd get would be:

- name NULL

If I didn't have the LIMIT in place, it would create a second row:

- name NULL
- NULL other

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the two columns to be different, you need to do a join between two instances of the same table.

```
SELECT firstTable.last AS firstLast, secondTable.last AS secondLast from table
 as firstTable inner join table as secondTable
 WHERE firstTable.last = 'name' and secondTable.last = 'other' LIMIT 1
```

The only thing that's missing here is how to connect the joins (the `on` statement). you can do without if you just want to get one 'name other' result and no other columns, but if there are other columns on the table, like id, you should use it to do the join

Comment: Thanks! Was able to get this to work without too much fiddling in my convoluted query with a number of other fields.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`CASE WHEN` construct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) in combination with aggregation (`MAX` or `MIN`). BTW, you can use `IN` instead of `OR` :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE last WHEN 'name'  THEN last END) AS firstLast,
       MAX(CASE last WHEN 'other' THEN last END) AS secondLast
FROM   mytable
WHERE  last IN ('name', 'other')
```

No need to use `LIMIT` because with `MAX` you are aggregating the result.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/968061/1)

Note that the above query is not very interesting, as it just outputs what you put in the `WHERE` clause.

You could instead select something that goes with that value of *last*. For instance the age of the corresponding person:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE last WHEN 'johnson' THEN age END) AS johnsons_age,
       MAX(CASE last WHEN 'clark'   THEN age END) AS clarks_age
FROM   mytable
WHERE  last IN ('johnson', 'clark')
```

Comment: This likely works just as well, in some incarnation. However, as I'd spent some time trying to get MAX and CASE working prior, I decided to try the other route and join them, which seems to be working well. Definitely appreciate the answer! :)

Comment: If you have other columns, then (depending which role they play), you might need a `GROUP BY`clause near the end. But you're right, the other solution works just as well. If you would have many such columns based on the same column (a 3rd, 4th, ....) then at a certain point this solution will be more time efficient though.

Comment: I actually did try 'GROUP BY' to narrow it down, among other possibilities. It always showed 'name NULL' (Equivalent) instead of the two items side by side. Additionally, there are three different sets of the same columns, which is likely the initial issue. But, if this is a more efficient approach ... most likely I'll be revisiting this later. Right now, it's all about quick solutions rather than most efficient. And... that's a weird statement coming from me...

Comment: ;-) No problem. Happy coding!